# Определение конца отрисовки/рендера страницы

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как то определить, что браузер закончил рендер/отрисовку (не путать с загрузкой) страницы ?

То есть предположим есть сайт, не мой, сторонний сайт ни как ко мне не относящийся на странице есть график, который рисуется браузером по подгруженным данным.

И вот как можно понять, что этот график в какой то конкретный момент - отрисован, отображен браузером на экране ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043017/7791165

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: Попробуйте использовать MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @entithat, "load" event, хоть в описании написано, что "Событие запускается, когда загружается вся страница, включая все зависимые ресурсы, такие как таблицы стилей и изображения." - однако Фактически "load" вызывается около 5 раз при загрузке одной страницы примеру youtube, а не Один раз - после полной загрузки и отображении ее на экране.